# Como verificar se um intervalo de tempo possui datas conflitantes com outro intervalo de tempo em php?

Tags: php, data

Estou construindo um sistema em php para verificar se um determinado intervalo de tempo possui datas conflitantes com outro intervalo de tempo. É possível fazer isso?

**Exemplo:**

Eu tenho dois intervalos de data: 10/05/2017 até 15/05/2017; e 18/04/2017 até 23/10/2017. Quero saber como verificar se o primeiro intervalo está contido dentro do segundo intervalo.

Comment: Seria bom explicar melhor a pergunta com exemplos.

Comment: Eu tenho dois intervalos de data: 10/05/2017 até 15/05/2017; e 18/04/2017 até 23/10/2017. Quero saber como verificar se o primeiro intervalo está contido dentro do segundo intervalo.

Comment: No caso do exemplo, seria conflitante, não é?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Comment: As datas são conflitantes apenas se um periodo estiver completamente dentro do outro? Ou são confiltantes se apenas uma parte de um periodo estiver dentro de outro periodo? Por exemplo, 10/05/2017 até 15/05/2017 e 12/05/2017 até 16/05/2017, são conflitantes também?

Comment: As datas são conflitantes se uma única parte de um período estiver dentro do outro também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma verificação bem simples:

```
($dt1_1 <= $dt2_2) && ($dt1_2 >= $dt2_1)
```

**Explicação:**

```
  10/05      15/05
    [- $dt1_x -]
  [--------------- $dt2_x ---------------]
18/04                                  23/10
```

- **`$dt1_1` (10/05) é menor ou igual do que `$dt2_2` (23/10)?** sim
- **`$dt1_2` (15/05) é maior ou igual do que `$dt2_1` (18/04)?** sim

Ambas as condições são *verdadeiras*, logo o intervalo `$dt1_1 -> $dt1_2` está contido no intervalo `$dt2_1 -> $dt2_2`.

---

**Exemplo quando for *falso*:**

```
10/05      15/05
  [- $dt1_x -]
              [----------- $dt2_x ------------]
            16/05                           23/10
```

- **`$dt1_1` (10/05) é menor ou igual do que `$dt2_2` (23/10)?** sim
- **`$dt1_2` (15/05) é maior ou igual do que `$dt2_1` (16/05)?** NÃO

**Código:**

```
$dt1_1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/","-","10/05/2017")));
$dt1_2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/","-","15/05/2017")));
$dt2_1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/","-","18/04/2017")));
$dt2_2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/","-","23/10/2017")));

if(($dt1_1 <= $dt2_2) && ($dt1_2 >= $dt2_1)){
    echo "True";
}else{
    echo "False";
}
```

**Obs.:** Os `replaces` nas datas são necessários: "*[To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)*"

Teste no **[Ideone](https://ideone.com/jFRRgn)**.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta. Resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!

Comment: @felipebrum ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) Obg!